# Deploying Rails App to AWS/EC2 Using Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I have a question about using the Rubber gem to deploy a Rails app to EC2. When I go about running

> cap rubber:create_staging

This line of code runs in a loop.

> executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
>      executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
>       servers: ["witheld"]
>   .  Failed to connect to witheld, retrying

I believe this may be an issue with my keypairs. 
In terms of my keynames, I have a current private key called keyname (plain text file) and a public key called keyname.pub in my config/rubber folder. My rubber.yml file lists

> key_name: keyname
>
> key_file: "#{Dir[(File.expand_path('~') rescue '/root') + '/.ec2/*' +    cloud_providers.aws.key_name].first}"

I'm pretty sure all other information is correct, but I obviously can't copy and paste it in. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

your keys should be in ~/.ec2/ folder not in config/rubber folder. also make sure you remove .pem extension from your private key file and .pub stays with your public file. 
Also change key_name: [your private key file name here] in your rubber.yml file.

based on your key_file: settings,  rubber will look for these keys in ~/.ec2 folder. So move them to there.